# TypeError - expected string or buffer for date field in django when using SelectDateWidget

Tags: django, django-models, django-widget

I have a date field in my model, and I am using SelectDateWidget() to provide the user date selection option. The name of the field is `deadline` and here is how I set the widget in the model form

```
widgets = {
        'deadline' : SelectDateWidget(),            
    }
```

Now the problem is when I submit the form I get the following error 
`TypeError - expected string or buffer`. I did some tweaking and found out that the Datewidget is returning a `bool` value instead of string.

If I remove the date widget and submit the date normally in YYYY-MM-DD format, everything works fine. Can anybody please help to understand what is actually going wrong here?

**Edit:** Adding my Model and Model form

```
class UniData(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, unique=True)
    SCORE_CHOICES = (
        (0 , 'Not Sent'),
        (1 , 'Sent'),
    )
    YES_NO = (
        (0 , 'NO'),
        (1 , 'YES'),
    )
    Score = models.IntegerField(choices=SCORE_CHOICES, default=0)

    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
    deadline = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    submitted = models.IntegerField(choices=YES_NO, default=1)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(null = True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-created_date',)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' %(self.name)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.universityName)
        super(UniData, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/ScoreTracker/%s/" % self.slug
```

And the **model form** is

```
class UniForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        fields = ['name', 'Score','deadline', 'submitted']
        widgets = {
            'name': TextInput(attrs={'value':'University Name', 'class':'default-value',}),
            'Score': RadioSelect(choices=SCORE_CHOICES),
            'submitted': RadioSelect(choices=YES_NO),
            'deadline': SelectDateWidget(),     
        }
```

Comment: So what's SelectDateWidget? Where's it from?

Comment: Here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/ `SelectDateWidget` has been used

Comment: can you actually post your model, please?